# Show that is not a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, product-space

I would like to pose a question to you, and I will appreciate any hint or partial solution for my question.

Let $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}\right)$ be a measurable space, and let $\left(\Omega \times \Omega, \mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{F}\right)$ be the product space of $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}\right)$ with itself.

Let $\mathcal{C}:= \left\{ A \times A : A \in \mathcal{F} \right\}$.

How can I show that $\mathcal{C}$ is not a sigma-algebra, but it is closed under finite intersections?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, this is not any homework or assignment: it is just a personal thing that I want to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as $\mathcal F\ne\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$, choose $A$ in $\mathcal F$, $A\ne\varnothing$, $A\ne\Omega$, and consider
$$
B=(A\times A)\cup(A^c\times A^c).
$$
Then $B$ is not in $\mathcal C$ while $A\times A$ and $A^c\times A^c$ are, hence $\mathcal C$ is not a sigma-algebra.

To show that $B$ is not in $\mathcal C$, consider that, for every $C$, if $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$ are in $C\times C$ then $x$ and $y$ are in $C$ hence $(x,y)$ is in $C\times C$. But, if $x$ is in $A$ and $y$ in $A^c$ then $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$ are in $B$ while $(x,y)$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Intersections.2C_unions.2C_and_subsets) says that $(A \times C) \cap (B \times D) = (A \cap B) \times (C \cap D)$ from which it follows that it is closed with respect to finite intersection.

That it is not a $\sigma$-algebra stems from the fact that it is not necessarily closed with respect to unions. After all how in general can you write $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D)$ as $U \times V$?